# Chain of C libraries into C++

Tags: c++, c, g++, extern

I have a very trivial problem including a chain of C libraries into a C++ main project. I've experience with C but it's the first time that I'm programming in C++.

The structure of the project is a single folder with inside:

- main.cpp
- Mylib_1.c
- Mylib_1.h
- Mylib_2.c
- Mylib_2.h

---

main calls -> Mylib_1.h that calls ->  My_lib2.h

```
//main.cpp
#include "Mylib_1.h"

//Mylib_1.h
#include "Mylib_2.h"
```

---

main contains both Mylib_1 and Mylib_2 functions and typedef structs

Mylib_1 uses typedef structs and functions of Mylib_2

---

Everything inside each Mylib_x.h is wrapped between extern "C", like this:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_X_H
#define __MYLIB_X_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

mycode         

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif 

#endif
```

---

But when I try to compile it with eclipse kepler on Ubuntu 12.04 x64, I get:

> Mylib_1.h error: Mylib_2_type_t does not name a type
>
> main.cpp  error: Mylib_2_function1 was not declared in this scope
>
> ...

Only the above sections are marked as error in eclipse, the header looks included fine.

Furthermore according to eclipse, the __cplusplus flag is false into Mylib_2.h but true into Mylib_1.h

Thinking of some eclipse error, I've tried to manually build the project via g++ (v4.6.3) but I got the same exact problem when I've tried to link the libraries .o with the main.cpp

Seems stupid but I can't figure out what could it be. Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: If you are thinking that the problem is with includes, I suggest you to look inside from what will be the file that will be compiled after the preprocessor has been executed. To do that, execute the g++ compiler with the `-E` option enabled and look inside the generated file to see if everything is ok. Begin with main.cpp file

Comment: Ok, I've checked both main.cpp and Mylib_1.c. Into Mylib_1.c everything seems fine: all the data from Mylib_2.h is there. In the main.cpp though, Mylib_2.h is named once but none of the data inside it is present...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your lines

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_X_H
#define __MYLIB_X_H
```

are really different for the two files,
e.g. _*MYLIB***1**_H and _*MYLIB***2**_H?